# awk query with numbers vs. strings

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I am writing a function in R that will generate an awk script to pull in rows from a csv according to conditions that a user selected through a UI.

This is the example of the string generated by the function:

```
$ tail -n +2 ../data/faults_main_only_dp_1_shopFlag.csv |
>     parallel -k -q --block 500M --pipe \
>         awk -F , '$5 > "2013-01-01" && $5 < "2015-11-05" && ($3 == "20116688") && ($20 == "Disregard") {print  $1 "," $3 "," $17 "," $20 }' |
> head | csvlook
```

It doesn’t return anything because `$3` is a numeric variable. Neither does:

```
$ tail -n +2 ../data/faults_main_only_dp_1_shopFlag.csv |
>     parallel -k -q --block 500M --pipe \
>         awk -F , '$5 > "2013-01-01" && $5 < "2015-11-05" && ($3 == 20116688) && ($20 == Disregard) {print  $1 "," $3 "," $17 "," $20 }' |
> head | csvlook
```

… because `$20` is a string.

This returns a portion of the dataset:

```
$ tail -n +2 ../data/faults_main_only_dp_1_shopFlag.csv |
>     parallel -k -q --block 500M --pipe \
>         awk -F , '$5 > "2013-01-01" && $5 < "2015-11-05" && ($3 == 20116688) && ($20 == "Disregard") {print $1 "," $3 "," $17 "," $20 }' |
> head | csvlook`

|---------+------------+------+------------|
|  5058.0 | 20116688.0 | 4162 | Disregard  |
|---------+------------+------+------------|
|  5060.0 | 20116688.0 | 3622 | Disregard  |
|  5060.0 | 20116688.0 | 3619 | Disregard  |
|  5061.0 | 20116688.0 | 766  | Disregard  |
|  5059.0 | 20116688.0 | 3603 | Disregard  |
|  5055.0 | 20116688.0 | 1013 | Disregard  |
|  5058.0 | 20116688.0 | 1012 | Disregard  |
|  5055.0 | 20116688.0 | 4163 | Disregard  |
|  5060.0 | 20116688.0 | 4225 | Disregard  |
|  5061.0 | 20116688.0 | 3466 | Disregard  |
|---------+------------+------+——————|
```

Unfortunately, I don’t currently have a way of anticipating which of the variables that the user selects through the UI will be string or numerical (I know how to do that, but it will take time that I’d rather not spend if there was a workaround). Is there a way to cast each variable a string before the comparison or have some other way of dealing with this issue?

**Edit** This is what the raw data look like:

```
$ csvcut -c15:20 faults_main_only_dp_1_shopFlag.csv | head
faultActiveLongitude,faultActiveAltitude,faultCode,faultSoftwareVersion,stateID,stateName
-0.8100106,-1.0,3604,25.07.01 11367,2.0,Work Item
-0.81860137,840.0,766,25.07.01 11367,5.0,Disregard
-0.8100140690000001,-1.0,4279,25.07.01 11367,2.0,Work Item
-0.8100509640000001,-2.0,4279,25.07.01 11367,2.0,Work Item
-0.8102342,14.0,3604,25.07.01 11367,2.0,Work Item
-0.8181563620000001,831.0,3604,25.07.01 11367,5.0,Disregard
-0.81022054,11.0,3604,25.07.01 11367,2.0,Work Item
-0.8102272,11.0,4279,25.07.01 11367,2.0,Work Item
-0.8083836999999999,17.0,766,25.07.01 11367,5.0,Disregard
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Everything in awk is a string, so your first try should be working, unless the data coming in actually has the `.0` on the numbers. In which case you should be saying `$3 == "20116688.0"`.

Comment: The data doesn’t have .0, but when I import that column into R, it’s not an integer, but a numerical.

Comment: What does the actual data you're feeding into awk look like, outside csvlook or whatever?

Answer (score 0):

awk can do the int `<-->` string comparison if the token can be converted.  Note that you're using comma as the field separator and spaces will be part of the fields.  If it's not a decimal point issue where your numbers are integers,

Check these three cases

```
$ echo "42,42" | awk -F, '$1=="42" && $2==42{print "works";next} {print "does not work"}'
works

$ echo "42, 42" | awk -F, '$1=="42" && $2==42{print "works";next} {print "does not work"}'
works

$ echo "42 , 42" | awk -F, '$1=="42" && $2==42{print "works";next} {print "does not work"}'
does not work
```

The string interpretation (first field) should not have the space!

You can try setting up your field separator to `" *, *"`

UPDATE:  If your integers get `.0` floating point extensions which you can ignore, convert the them to `int` before the comparison

```
$ echo "42.0 , 42" | awk -v FS=" *, *" 'int($1)=="42" && $2=="42"{print "works";next} {print "does not work"}'
works
```

Here your generic value will be quoted but the field will be converted to int before the string conversion.  You need to know what fields are numeric what fields are string though.

Comment: But in my example there are no spaces in either “Disregard” or the numericals.

Comment: I assumed that your numbers are integers.  If they have decimal points (floats) the string comparison will fail obviously.

Comment: They don’t have decimal points, as far as I am aware, but when I import that csv into R, they are treated not as integers, but as “numericals”.

Comment: You are piping text into awk, nothing else. Find out what that text looks like.